# Warning in php URL routing using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I'm new to CodeIgniter and I'm trying some practice codes. In that, I have created a function with 2 parameters, `$p1` and `$p2`. My function is working with default parameters too. Now I'm trying to give one parameter in the code and the other in the URL, here `$p2="Nimishan"`.

```
<?php
class Hello extends CI_Controller{
    public function first($p1,$p2="Nimishan"){
        echo "This is the first method<br>";
        echo "My parameters are : $p1 and $p2";
    }
}
?>
```

And my URL is :
`localhost/code/index.php/hello/first/hey`
So the output is

> hey, Nimishan

but the warning I get when I change the default parameter value to `$p1`.

```
<?php
class Hello extends CI_Controller{
public function first($p1="Hello",$p2){
    echo "This is the first method<br>";
    echo "My parameters are : $p1 and $p2";
    }
}
?>
```

I tried the URL to get the correct output in different ways.

> eg:localhost/code/index.php/hello/first/nimishan

but I get Warnings

```
Severity: Warning
Message: Missing argument 2 for Hello::first()

Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: p2
```

I'm not sure where I'm missing.

What I want is to get the correct output by giving value for the first parameter, instead of the second and the correct way of URL.

Comment: You have to use segments inside codeigniter for getting the values from route from url , the way you are treating the controller and putting parameters inside it , it's wrong. use $this->uri->segment(); inside controller and remove parameters from function. all the data inside url is inside segment.

Comment: Unrelated: I saw your vote for EDIT on https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20858659 . Wrong choice: this question is way too broad, and there is no chance that anybody but the OP can fix this question. It should have been closed as too broad. Please study the help for the triage queue and be more careful about your votes. AND: your EDIT that you made is "wrong", too. We dont EDIT such postings, we close vote them, if at all, we drop a comment to the questioner and ask him to improve his low quality input.

Answer (score 3):

open your CodeIgniter config.php file which is located in application\config\config.php please check below $config array values are configured properly or not.

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = ''; // a-z 0-9~%.:_\-
$config['encryption_key'] = ''; //Some unique random string
```

Answer (score 2):

This is valid.

```
public function first($p1,$p2="Nimishan"){}
```

but following is invalid

```
public function first($p1="Hello",$p2){}
```

However it is not Codeigniter issue rather this is PHP's rule. Always default value of paramters must be placed from last. If no default value required for rest of the params then you may assign null or something else. so you can use as

```
public function first($p1="Hello",$p2 = NULL){}
```

Comment: `public function first($p1="Hello",$p2 = NULL){}`If I use this how the URL should be?

Comment: whatever your URL now, no error/warning will be shown anymore. like run this `localhost/code/index.php/hello/first/nimishan` and check no error anyomre

Comment: no error, fine. But the output is `nimishan , `. I want `Hello, nimishan`

Comment: then use `public function first($p1="Hello",$p2 = 'nimishan'){}` or You may change `$p1` & `$p2` on method call as required

Comment: it is the basic parameter passing. and I did it. now I'm trying to give `p1` a default value and the value for `p2` in the URL. `localhost/code/index.php/hello/first/p1/nimishan` here the `p1` is already given. how to get rid of the p1 in the URL?

Comment: then you may remove `$p1` from parameter & set it in method. so now your method could be `public function first($p2 = 'nimishan'){$p1 = 'Hello';}`
Now URL `localhost/code/index.php/hello/first/nimishan` will output as `Hello, nimishan`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115477/discussion-between-nimishan-and-rejoanul-alam).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do something like this -

```
public function first() {
    $p1 = $this->uri->segment(1);
    $p2 = $this->uri->segment(2);
    echo "This is the first method<br>";
    echo "My parameters are : $p1 and $p2";
    }
}
```

so if your URL was `http://localhost/code/index.php/hello/first/welcome/nimishan` 
this->uri->segment(1) would be "welcome", segment(2) as "nimishan" and so on.

if your URL was `http://localhost/code/index.php/hello/first/ both $p1 and $p2 would be NULL.

If you need to pass on default values you can provide the default value e.g.

```
$p1 = $this->uri->segment(1, 'Hello');
$p2 = $this->uri->segment(2, 'Nimishan');
```

Comment: I wanted to give the first parameter p1 in the code and the next parameter in the URL. The question is `How?`